# SQL logic for Decompression

Tags: sql

RDW (Retake Data Warehouse) used to reduce data volume by compression logic. Compression refers to storing physical data that only reflects changes to the underlying data source.

Inventory fact table store data in following form.

```
Week        Item        Location    stock_on_hand
--------------------------------------------------
201601      I1          L1          50
201602      I1          L1          30
201605      I1          L1          60
201608      I1          L1          50
```

But I need sql query to get following result

```
Week        Item        Location    stock_on_hand
--------------------------------------------------
201601      I1          L1          50
201602      I1          L1          30
201603      I1          L1          30
201604      I1          L1          30
201605      I1          L1          60
201606      I1          L1          60
201607      I1          L1          60
201608      I1          L1          50
```

Answer (score 1):

Test data(I add several rows for better understanding and split year and week columns)

```
with t(year, Week , Item, Location,  stock_on_hand) as
(select 2016, 01,      'I1',          'L1',          50 from dual union all
select 2016, 02,      'I1',          'L1',          30 from dual union all
select 2016 ,05,      'I1',          'L1',          60 from dual union all
select 2016 ,08,      'I1',          'L1',          50 from dual union all
select 2016, 02,      'I2',          'L1',          30 from dual union all
select 2016, 08,      'I2',          'L1',          40 from dual union all
select 2016, 02,      'I1',          'L2',          10 from dual union all
select 2016, 08,      'I1',          'L2',          40 from dual union all
select 2016, 08,      'I1',          'L3',          40 from dual)
```

Query

```
with t(year, Week , Item, Location,  stock_on_hand) as
(select 2016, 01,      'I1',          'L1',          50 from dual union all
select 2016, 02,      'I1',          'L1',          30 from dual union all
select 2016 ,05,      'I1',          'L1',          60 from dual union all
select 2016 ,08,      'I1',          'L1',          50 from dual union all
select 2016, 02,      'I2',          'L1',          30 from dual union all
select 2016, 08,      'I2',          'L1',          40 from dual union all
select 2016, 02,      'I1',          'L2',          10 from dual union all
select 2016, 08,      'I1',          'L2',          40 from dual union all
select 2016, 08,      'I1',          'L3',          40 from dual),
temp(year, Week , Item,   Location,  stock_on_hand, ct) as(
select year, Week , Item,   Location,  stock_on_hand, nvl(lead(Week) over(partition by Item, Location order by year, Week)-Week,1) from t)
 select year, Week + rn - 1 as week, Item, Location,  stock_on_hand
    from temp, xmltable('1 to xs:integer($ct)' passing ct as "ct" columns rn number path '.')
    order by Item, Location ,year, week
```

This approach also have one minor. If you have interval in different year. Ex

```
select 2016, 01,      'I1',          'L1',          50 from dual union all
select 2017, 02,      'I1',          'L1',          30 from dual union all
```

Then it works incorrectly. I don't know whether you data has the same pattern. If it has then, please, add information to post or answer.

**UPDATE**
For intervals which lives in several years you can do follow(For startDate I choose date in international week)

```
with t(dateStart , Item, Location,  stock_on_hand) as
(select to_date('28/12/2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),     'I1',          'L1',          50 from dual union all
select to_date('04/01/2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),      'I1',          'L1',          30 from dual union all
select to_date('25/01/2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),      'I1',          'L1',          60 from dual union all
select to_date('15/02/2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),      'I1',          'L1',          50 from dual union all
select to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),      'I1',          'L1',          30 from dual union all
select to_date('04/01/2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),      'I2',          'L1',          40 from dual union all
select to_date('15/02/2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),      'I2',          'L1',          10 from dual union all
select to_date('04/01/2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),      'I1',          'L2',          30 from dual union all
select to_date('15/02/2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),      'I1',          'L2',          40 from dual union all
select to_date('15/02/2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),      'I1',          'L3',          40 from dual),
temp(dateStart, Item,   Location,  stock_on_hand, ct) as(
select dateStart , Item,   Location,  stock_on_hand, nvl((lead(dateStart) over(partition by Item, Location order by dateStart)-dateStart)/7,1) from t)
select dateStart + (rn - 1)*7 as week, Item, Location,  stock_on_hand
    from temp, xmltable('1 to xs:integer($ct)' passing ct as "ct" columns rn number path '.')
    order by Item, Location , dateStart
```